# The limit of a function over a base

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, limits

I am reading Zorich's *Mathemematical Analysis I*, and he defines:

> A set $\mathcal{B}$ of subsets $B\subset X$ of a set $X$ is called a *base* in $X$ if the following conditions hold:
>
> $B_1)$ For all $B\in\mathcal{B}$, $B\neq\varnothing$.
>
> $B_2)$ For all $B_1\in\mathcal{B}$ and $B_2\in\mathcal{B}$, there exists $B\in\mathcal{B}$ such that $B\subset (B_1\cap B_2)$.

Then, one may define a limit over a base as

> Let $f\colon X\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a function defined on a set $X$ and $\mathcal{B}$ a base in $X$. A number $A\in\mathbb{R}$ is called the *limit of the function* $f$ *over the base* $\mathcal{B}$ if for every neighborhood $V(A)$ of $A$ there is an element $B\in\mathcal{B}$ whose image $f(B)$ is contained in $V(A)$.

I have two main questions. First, where does the $B_1$ and $B_2$ parts come from? The author mentions that they are all that is needed to prove the properties of limits, but I'm not exactly sure what that means. And second, what is the point of defining a limit over a base? What's wrong with "normal" limits? It seems like we have to pick what base we are using each time anyways, and are we losing any of the metric space structure of $\mathbb{R}$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While sequences — which ones converge, and to what limits — are sufficient to determine the topology of metric spaces, this is not the case for topological spaces in general. For the general case one needs something more general. There are two standard generalizations of sequences that are adequate for all spaces, [nets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Net_(mathematics)) and [filters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filter_(mathematics)#Filter_on_a_set); the former look more like sequences, but the latter are often easier to use. Each, however, comes with a notion of convergence, and the topology of every space is completely determined by which nets or filters in it converge, and to what limits.

Zorich is defining what is more usually called a *filter base*. A filter base is essentially the skeleton of a filter, and the filter base converges to a point if and only if the associated filter does. Thus, the topology of a space is also completely determined by its [convergent filter bases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filter_(mathematics)#Convergent_filter_bases), even if the space is not a metric space.

From the bit that I can see at Google Books it does not appear that Zorich makes much use of this greater generality right away. As he says, at that point his main use is to take advantage of the fact that many results about limits can be proved once and for all for bases in general, so that he won’t need to prove them individually for each type of limit (type of base) that comes up.

The two clauses of the definition are simply what turn out to be needed to make filter bases do their intended job, but perhaps I can give an analogy with ordinary sequences that makes them seem a little less mysterious. When we say that a sequence $\langle x_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ converges to $x$, we mean that for each nbhd $V$ of $x$ there is an $n_0\in\Bbb N$ such that $x_n\in V$ for all $n\ge n_0$. If for each $n\in\Bbb N$ we set $T_n=\{x_k:k\ge n\}$, the $n$-tail of the sequence, then the sequence converges to $x$ if and only if for each nbhd $V$ of $x$ there is an $n\in\Bbb N$ such that $T_n\subseteq V$. Notice that none of the tails $T_n$ is empty, and the intersection of any two tails of the sequence contains a tail of the sequence. (In fact $T_m\cap T_n=T_{\max\{m,n\}}$, so the intersection of two tails actually *is* a tail.) It turns out that we can think of the members of a filter base $\mathscr{B}$ as being rather like the tails of a sequence.

- Like tails of a sequence, members of $\mathscr{B}$ are never empty. (You can also think of that as being analogous to the fact that an ordinary infinite sequence has no last term.)
- And for any two members $B_0$ and $B_1$ of $\mathscr{B}$ there is some $B\in\mathscr{B}$ that is contained in both of them; in a sense it is ‘beyond’ both of them, just as the tail $T_{107}$ is ‘beyond’ the tails $T_{87}$ and $T_{47}$ of the sequence $\langle x_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$.

These two characteristics of sequences and their tails turn out to be the crucial components of a general notion of convergence. And to return to more familiar ground, sequences in their usual form are a special case of nets, while sequences viewed in terms of their tails are a special case of filter bases.

Comment: When you mention that "at that point his main use is to take advantage of the fact that many results about limits can be proved once and for all for bases in general", do you mean that since there are many types of limits $x\rightarrow a$, $x\rightarrow \infty$, etc., the filter base definition allows us to prove stuff for all of these at the same time?

Comment: And, sorry for the questions, could we define a filter base in a way that does not match up with "normal" ideas of convergence on $\mathbb{R}$? For example, the limit of a function $f(x)$ as $x\rightarrow a$ has a filter base as the collection of punctured neighborhoods at $a$. Could we define some other type of collection that has a "limit", different from what we are used to?

Comment: @Vasting: Yes, all of those are instances of the underlying idea that is captured by his bases. You can get some variation by changing the filter base, but it’s limited as long as you’re talking about ordinary open nbhds. For instance, if $a\in\Bbb R$, $f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ is a function, and you let $$\mathscr{B}=\{[a,b):a<b\in\Bbb R\}\,,$$ you’ll find that the limit of $f$ over $\mathscr{B}$ is $f(a)$ iff $$\lim_{x\to a^+}f(x)=f(a)\,.$$ This $\mathscr{B} captures the notion of *limit from the right*.

Comment: Ah okay. Thank you!

Comment: @Vasting: You’re welcome!

Comment: Indeed, Zorich himself comments in the book (Analysis I, 2nd Edition): "..We note also that the term “base” used here is an abbreviation for what is called a “filter base”, and the limit over a base that we introduce below is, as far as analysis is concerned, the most important part of the concept of a limit over a filter, created by the modern French mathematician H. Cartan."